# QTcpSocket.connectToHost() takes too long time

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket, qt5.9

This is my code for connection with custom TcpServer. In result connectiontoHost() is complitted in 13.5 seconds (some times in 2.5 seconds).
Connection to localserver is very fast.
**The same code with the remote server, but on Qt5.7 works very quickly.**

```
bool cuTcpSocketIOInterface::pInitialize()
{
    QTcpSocket* tSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();
    if (!isSocketReady()){
       qDebug()<<"connectToHost" <<address()<<port()<<", Time:"
               <<timer.elapsed();
       tSocket->connectToHost(address(), port());
    }
    qDebug()<<"Done:"<<timer.elapsed();
    tSocket->waitForConnected(100);
    return tSocket->state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState;
}
```

And next is a output of this function in std::out with remote server:

```
connectToHost QHostAddress("192.168.255.193") 9876 , Time: 0
Done: 13581
```

Connection with custom localserver

```
connectToHost QHostAddress("127.0.0.1") 9876 , Time: 0
Done: 5
```

Ping to my custom remote server is very well (less than 1 ms). Connection with putty is very quickly.

**Update**
So, I try work with Qt5.7 and Qt 5.9.1. And I obtain next results:
My code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    qDebug()<<"START TEST!!!";
    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();

    QTcpSocket socket;
    socket.connectToHost(TcpIpAddress,80);
    qDebug()<<"connectToHost Done:"<<timer.elapsed();

    return a.exec();
}
```

On Qt 5.7.1:

```
START TEST!!!
connectionToHost Done:7
```

On Qt 5.9:

```
START TEST!!!
connectionToHost Done:2572
```

Looks it like an excuse for BugReport?

**Update:** on Qt 5.10.1

```
START TEST!!!
connectionToHost Done:2574
```

Comment: place `qDebug()<<"Done:"<<timer.elapsed();` after `waitForConnected` otherwise it is meaningless

Comment: Ok,  added `bool result = tSocket->waitForConnected(100);
    qDebug()<<"Connected:"<<result<<"Time:"<<timer.elapsed();`.Result: `connectToHost QHostAddress("192.168.255.193") 9876 , Time: 0 
Done: 13582
Connected: true Time: 13583`

Comment: Good chance that the issue is a slow lookup to your DNS server. Take a look at Wireshark, it may give you clues

Comment: I tried to work with WireShark. After calling the procedure, it takes 2.5-14 seconds, then simultaneously with the output of the successful connection, information appears on the packets sent

Comment: Try writing asynchronous code that reacts to socket's state changes, instead of synchronous code like you wrote above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**
Need to setting up proxy before connecting to server:
`socket.setProxy(QNetworkProxy::NoProxy)`